# Capture updated text from h tag after change in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, events, shiny

I am new to Javascript.So please excuse me if I am asking anything silly. I have a sample Shiny application [Statistics Dashboard](https://avinashr.shinyapps.io/statistics_dashboard/) which can be used to find some basic statistical measures such as Mean, Median etc. for any metric. Users have to upload a csv file based on which the dashboard selects all the numeric variables within the file and provides an option to select any numeric variable to analyze as a dropdown. I want to add a javascript code in the application which will capture the updated measures (e.g. mean) after a user has selected a particular dimension from the dropdown. For example, suppose the default selected dimension in the dropdown window is "sales" and the corresponding mean is 325. If I select another dimension (suppose) "profit" then the mean changes to 37. Now I want to add a javascript/jquery code which will capture the mean value of 37 when I select "profit" (from "sales") from the dropdown. I have tried the **.change** event to check for the change in the dropdown selection and when there is a change, capture the mean value inside the **h3** tag. However, I am getting the previous mean value instead of the updated one i.e. I am getting 325 instead of 37 when I select "profit" (from "sales"). Hope I am clear on this.

Am I using the wrong event? How can I capture anything after a certain action occurs and the values are updated?

Feel free to let me know if you need any more details on my query. Looking forward to the help from the community.

Comment: what have u tried to achieve this? Atleast post some code?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have to include some code mate. This is for us to help you more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is Exactly what you are looking for

Here is a code which will detect any changes in a certain element.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="Profit"></input>
<h3 id="MeanLabel">100</h3>
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Profit").on("change", function()
    {
        $("#MeanLabel").text(this.value);

    });

    initialValue = $("#MeanLabel").text();
    CheckChanges();
})


function CheckChanges()
{

    if($("#MeanLabel").text() != initialValue)
    {
        //The Label Changes!
        initialValue = $("#MeanLabel").text();
        alert("New Label is: " + initialValue) 

    }
    setTimeout(CheckChanges, 200)
}
```

This is the working sample.

https://jsfiddle.net/h68nxu4h/

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank You so much Bryan.